# Mongoose group by field and sum

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I use MongoDB and Mongoose as my ODM in next.js and i'm trying group by user and calculate all amounts

Here is my simple documents models :

```
const bonusFillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    }, {
    timestamps: true
})
}

let Dataset = mongoose.models.bonusFill || mongoose.model('bonusFill', bonusFillSchema)
export default Dataset
```

I'm just trying to get every bonusFill for one user, group by each users he talks with. I tried like this :

```
import Fill from '../../../models/bonusFill'
const fills = await Fill.find()
```

Output

```
{
    "fills": [
        {
            "_id": "63244477301b6fd9d3116d37",
            "user": "631ce46b9bed2e97ba77a0a3",
            "amount": 100,
            "createdAt": "2022-09-16T09:40:07.179Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-09-16T09:40:07.179Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "63244487301b6fd9d3116d67",
            "user": "631ce46b9bed2e97ba77a0a3",
            "amount": 120,
            "createdAt": "2022-09-16T09:40:23.017Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-09-16T09:40:23.017Z",
        },
{
            "_id": "63244487301b6fd9d3116d67",
            "user": "632ce66b9bqd2e97baa795a4",
            "amount": 50,
            "createdAt": "2022-09-16T09:40:23.017Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-09-16T09:40:23.017Z",
        },
    ]
}
```

Expected Output

```
{
    "fills": [
        {
            "user": "631ce46b9bed2e97ba77a0a3",
            "amount": 220,
        },
        {
            "user": "632ce66b9bqd2e97baa795a4",
            "amount": 50,
        },
    ]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add some input documents and the expected output

Comment: @CharchitKapoor added. any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

i found solution. thanks!

```
const fills = await Fill.aggregate([
        {"$group": {_id: "$_id", user: {"$first": "$user"}, amount: {$sum: "$amount"}}}
    ]).sort({ amount: 'desc' })
res.status(200).json({sponsor: fills})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).